# MySQL; limiting records from one table when selecting from three

Tags: mysql

Im trying to pull a collection of 'Persons' from my database, to display as a list in a HTML page. A Person can belong to one or more categories. A person can have one or more photos.

What I'd like to do is fetch a collection of Persons that belong to a particular category, which is fairly straightforward even for me:

> SELECT * FROM persons, personcategorylookup WHERE
>   personcategorylookup.personUID = persons.uID AND
>   personcategorylookup.categoryUID = 1

However, I'd also like to grab the latest uploaded photo for each person. They may have uploaded many photos but I just want the latest, based on uploadDate in the photos table.

I have tried the following query:

> SELECT * FROM persons, personcategorylookup, photos WHERE
>   personcategorylookup.personUID = persons.uID AND
>   personcategorylookup.categoryUID = 1 AND photos.personUID =
>   persons.uID

However this obviously does not limit the number of records coming in from the photos table, so I end up with multiple records for each Person.

**What I actually want to do is this:**

> SELECT * FROM persons, personcategorylookup, photos … … … ORDER BY
>   photosTableOnly uploadDate LIMIT photosTableOnly 0, 1

I have also tried a UNION SELECT query but the number of columns differ so that doesn’t work.

And lastly, I tried a subquery which does work but apparently I can only pull one column at a time with those and I feel that I am probably hammering the MySQL server unnecessarily:

> SELECT *, (SELECT source FROM persons, photos WHERE personUID =
>   persons.uID ORDER BY uploadDate LIMIT 0, 1) AS source FROM persons,
>   personcategorylookup WHERE personcategorylookup.personUID =
>   persons.uID AND personcategorylookup.categoryUID = 1

My tables are as follows:

Person Table

```
PK int uID
VARCHAR name
```

Category Table

```
PK int uID
VARCHAR label
```

PersonCategoryLookup Table

```
PK personUID
PK categoryUID
```

Photos Table

```
PK personUID
PK photoSource
DATETIME uploadDate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming upload date is unique for a person, use a sub query to get the latest photo date for each person and join that against the photos table:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM persons
INNER JOIN personcategorylookup ON personcategorylookup.personUID = persons.uID
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT personUID, MAX(uploadDate) AS latest_photo_date
    FROM photos 
    GROUP BY personUID
) sub0
ON sub0.personUID = persons.uID
INNER JOIN photos ON sub0.personUID = photos.personUID AND sub0.latest_photo_date = photos.uploadDate
WHERE personcategorylookup.categoryUID = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    persons 
JOIN 
    personcategorylookup ON (personcategorylookup.personUID = persons.uID AND  personcategorylookup.categoryUID = 1)
LEFT JOIN 
    photos ON (persons.uID = photos.personUID)
GROUP BY persons.uID;
```

Here's fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d68b1/1

**NOTICE:** It was correctly pointed out by @Kickstart that it's undefined which photo you get for each person, due to undefined behavior of GROUP BY in such case.

Comment: Thanks very much, this works exactly as intended, pulling just the latest photo for each person retrieved by the query.

Comment: Problem is the relies on undefined behaviour of MySQL, which could change on any version (or even a change of storage engine). The GROUP BY reduces it to a single row returned for each persons.uID. If there are more than one row then the values of the other columns could come from any of those rows, and it is not defined as to which rows values it would chose (so it might be the latest photo, or the first, or any other, and whichever it is now can change in the future).

Comment: That is correct. I forgot about the "latest" part and somehow thought it was irrelevant which photo you get. I suggest you use subquery approach, which @Kickstart provided to achieve exactly what you needed, that is actual _latest_ photo for each person.